# I cannot retrieve json data from php with Angular $http.get

Tags: php, json, angularjs

This my php code

```
    <?php


try {
    $dbcon=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=angular;charset=utf8',"root","");

    $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $query="SELECT * FROM products ";
    $sql=$dbcon->prepare($query);
    $sql->execute();
    $result=$sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $json_result=json_encode($result);

    echo $json_result;

}catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

and this my controller to angular

```
  function ProductListCtrl($http)
{

    $http.get('api/products.php').success(function (data) { alert(data); this.product = data; });

}
```

the alert message is [object Object,...] ,how can i retrieve the json data from php?

Comment: That is the json object, if you want to alert it as a string you probably want `JSON.stringify(data)`. Otherwise in your code you should be able to just access the properties (i.e. data.foo.bar)

Comment: the problem is i think that `$http.get` do not retrieve json data ,for some reason from the php script.

Comment: Which is why I have a solution to check that, it'll be null, an empty array, or empty object in your alert if it didn't succeed. Another easy way to check is to run `curl http://host:port/path`

Answer (score 0):

$http.get work fine with JSON 
I recommend you to [validate](https://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) your json and test again
I created a simple example for you with $http and ng-repeat

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('test', []);
      app.controller('test', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('test.json').success(function(data){
          console.log(data);
          $scope.items = data;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="test">
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the json file is

```
[{
  "name":"name1"
},
{
  "name":"name2"
}]
```

and also a link to watch it live in Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/MN6UPg1ba1OYNFNHKMdG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.The wrong is with this.product

```
(function ()
{
    "use strict";
   var app = angular.module('ProductList');
   app.controller('ProductListCtrl',['$scope','$http', ProductListCtrl]);

   function ProductListCtrl($scope, $http) {

       $http.get('api/products.php').success(function (data) { $scope.product = data; });




   }

}());
```